# Using iter() with sentinel to replace while loops

Tags: python, generator

Oftentimes the case arises where one would need to loop indefinitely until a certain condition has been attained. For example, if I want keep collecting random integers until I find a number == n, following which I break. I'd do this:

```
import random

rlist = []
n = ...
low, high = ..., ...
while True:
    num = random.randint(low, high)
    if num == n:
        break
    rlist.append(num)
```

And this works, but is quite clunky. There is a much more pythonic alternative using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

> **iter(o[, sentinel])**
>
> Return an iterator object. The first argument is
>   interpreted very differently depending on the presence of the second
>   argument. [...] If the second argument,
>   sentinel, is given, then o must be a callable object. The iterator
>   created in this case will call o with no arguments for each call to
>   its `next()` method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel,
>   StopIteration will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

The loop above can be replaced with

```
import random
from functools import partial

f = partial(random.randint, low, high)
rlist = list(iter(f, 10))
```

To extend this principle to lists that have already been created, a slight change is needed. I'll need to define a partial function like this:

```
f = partial(next, iter(x)) # where x is some list I want to keep taking items from until I hit a sentinel
```

The rest remains the same, but the main caveat with this approach versus the while loop is *I cannot apply generic boolean conditions*.

For example, I cannot apply a "generate numbers until the first even number greater than 1000 is encountered".

---

The bottom line is this: Is there another alternative to the while loop and `iter` that supports a callback sentinel?

Comment: Why is the `while` loop "clunky"?

Comment: who is downvoting without explanation? have some class?

Comment: It's kinda bulky and old-fashioned. I've nothing against it though. Just wanted to explore other options. Also, would appreciate a comment from the down voter. Would like the opportunity to fix any mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want generic boolean conditions, then `iter(object, sentinel)` is insufficiently expressive for your needs. `itertools.takewhile()`, in contrast, seems to be more or less what you want: It takes an iterator, and cuts it off once a given predicate stops being true.

```
rlist = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x >= 20, inputlist))
```

Incidentally, `partial` is not very Pythonic, and neither is `itertools`. GvR is on record as disliking higher-order functional-style programming (note the downgrading of `reduce` from built-in to a module member in 3.0). Attributes like "elegant" and "readable" are in the eye of the beholder, but if you're looking for *Pythonic* in the purest sense, you want the while loop.

Comment: Brilliant. This is _precisely_ what I wanted. An `iter` capable of accepting a callback as a sentinel. Will accept when I can.

Comment: @Sneftel `partial` was added as part of GvR's attempt to get rid of `lambda`. `itertools` implements stream processing, which has close ties to functional programming but is not the same thing. Neither is un-Pythonic, just not deemed to be essential to the core language.

Comment: (*Parts* of `itertools` are moving to the core language, though. The built-in `map` and `filter` replaced `itertools.imap` and `itertools.ifilter`, for instance.)